# Do all bosses drop the same items across quests?

Tags: theatrhythm-curtain-call

For example, I have a Quest Medley with Jumbo Flan as a boss. I beat him and he drops Zeus's Wrath. If a different Quest Medley also has a Jumbo Flan as a boss do I know that it also drops a Zeus's Wrath or is the drop list unique to each quest even for identical bosses?